# WPF Notify content change when it's property changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, auto-update

I've set label `Content` to some custom class:

```
<Label>
    <local:SomeContent x:Name="SomeContent" some="abc" />
</Label>
```

This properly displays "abc" in a view. However I can't figure out how do I notify the `Label` that the content property have changed i.e. this:

```
SomeContent.some = "xyz";
```

Will not cause the label to update it's view.

I know I can set binding to label's `Content` property. I have already like 7 different, working methods to achieve automatic update. However I'm interested in this particular behavior because it will save me a ton of work in some scenarios i.e the requirements are:

- Label content is always the same `SomeContent` instance, only it's properties are changed.
- No label content binding. The label should take a content object and refresh whenever the content is modified.
- Initial value of `some` property can be set in XAML
- `some` property can be changed in code, causing label refresh.

Am I missing something, or it's not possible?

This is my current implementation of `SomeContent`:

```
public class SomeContent : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty someProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(some), typeof(string),
            typeof(SomeContent),
            new PropertyMetadata("", onDPChange)
    );

    private static void onDPChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        (d as SomeContent).some = e.NewValue as String;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string some {
        get => (string)GetValue(someProperty);
        set {
            SetValue(someProperty, value);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(some))
            );
        }
    }


    public override string ToString() => some;
}
```

Comment: What is point of `SomeContent`. It feels like you are using it to do smething that can be achieved in better way. Maybe converter? Read on [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: As a note, it is pointless to set `(d as SomeContent).some = e.NewValue as String` in the PropertyChangedCallback of the `some` property. The property value has already changed when the callback is called. No need to it again.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event somewhere? Or how do you expect to get notified? By the way, the setter of a CLR wrapper for a dependency property should only call `SetValue`. If you want to do something else when the value is changed, you should do it in the callback.

Comment: It is also pointless to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for a dependency property. These properties do already notify about value changes.

Comment: Besides all that, your whole approach seems broken. If you want to write a control that displays the value of one of its properties, it should have some UI elements which do that, e.g. in a ControlTemplate of a custom control, or the XAML of a UserControl. Start reading here: [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Comment: Label is not updating because ToString() is only called once the Label is loaded. You have to use binding or reset the content of the label by assigning it a new SomeContent instance: "
      this.Label.Content = new SomeContent() {some = "Your code gives me a stroke"};"

Comment: "I'm interested in this particular behavior because it will save me a ton of work" -  I wonder how binding Label.Content to SomeContent.some is a ton of work.

Comment: @Clemens About `(d as SomeContent).some = e.NewValue as String` the property may be changed but when the component is first initialized from XAML, the `set` is not called.

Comment: @mm8 I expected that maybe label will subscribe to that event, since dependency property alone didn't caused an update.

Comment: @Clemens My content will be just transforming strings. I already have special, custom label for it but I would like to have above method so that any control that displays text could display my transformed string and it will display differently depending on properties of parent `Label`, `TextBox`, `TextBlock` or anything that could display some text...

Comment: Note that the property setter is not supposed to be called. When a dependency property is set from Bindings, Styles, etc., WPF directly calls SetValue. That's the reason why there must not be anything else than SetValue in the property setter.

Comment: Besides that, your approach just won't work. There is no notification mechanism that forces an invocation of the ToString() method. In order to have "transformed" strings, use a Binding Converter or a view model.

Comment: It turns out the code in question is working as I expected but I had other bug... Thank you all for interest and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: False alarm, it's still not working... @BionicCode It is, because I need a reference to `SomeContent` instance in the first place. You may argue that making 9 additional lines of code isn't much but if you think in terms of proportions - it's 10x of the work + much more room for errors... And if you plan to use this thousand times or more, it actually is a ton of work

Comment: No your argument is not valid. You could have a  reference to the label and access its Content property to get the SomeContent instance. Then you could define a global style that will set the content and bindings on every label control so that you don't have to repeat any code. Because you accepted an absurd answer using a timer to update properties I feel like I have to tell you that your approach is absolutely wrong. Why don't you make SomeContent extend ContentControl that knows how to display the content? Why don't you use styles to setup the binding automatically?

Comment: Why don't you use the Label, which already is a ContentControl, directly and set the Content property? What you trying to accomplish is possible but you have to do it different. Your sulution  is like two tons of code were one ton was already too much for you.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of SomeContent class since you are only using it like a Content property. Use the Label directly and you are done.

Comment: You are absolutely wrong. 1. The timer is just for test. 2 `SomeContent` suppose to only provide dynamically changeable text and I don't want it to impose how or where it should be displayed. 3. I don't want to style anything so maybe you tell me why should I use styles? 4. Because I would need to use binding and to specify a binding I first need to specify some property... I all I need is to simply specify text `x` that will be dynamically transformed to text `y` 4. How you consider one-liner a ton of work? The helper class is just one-time write and I can reuse it for any `IChangeNotifier`

Comment: But if you have shorter solution, then I will be pleased to see it. So far you only showed that you can criticize...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out it's not possible to do it without third side code. So I wrote a helper class to do it easy now.

**Dynamic object**

```
public class SomeContent : IChangeNotifer {
    public event Action<object> MODIFIED;

    private string _some;
    public string some {
        get => _some;
        set {
            _some = value;
            MODIFIED?.Invoke(this);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() => some;
}
```

You can add it to **xaml** file and it will be updated automatically. Single additional step is to add `UIReseter` somewhere bellow the elements that suppose to be auto-updated but that is needed only one for multiple contents in a tree.

**Usage**

```
<Window x:Class="DependencyContentTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DependencyContentTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UIReseter />
        <Label>
            <local:SomeContent x:Name="SomeContent" some="abcd" />
        </Label>
        <Grid>
            <Label>
                <local:SomeContent x:Name="nested" some="nyest"/>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    private Timer t;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        t = new Timer(onTimer, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
        MouseDown += (s,e) => { SomeContent.some = "iii"; };
    }

    private void onTimer(object state) {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            SomeContent.some = "aaaa";
            nested.some = "xxx";
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the **helper class that handles the update**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using H = System.Windows.LogicalTreeHelper;
using FE = System.Windows.FrameworkElement;
using DO = System.Windows.DependencyObject;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace DependencyContentTest
{
    public interface IChangeNotifer {
        /// <summary>Dispatched when this object was modified.</summary>
        event Action<object> MODIFIED;
    }

    /// <summary>This element tracks nested <see cref="IChangeNotifer"/> descendant objects (in logical tree) of this object's parent element and resets a child in it's panel property.
    /// Only static (XAML) objects are supported i.e. object added to the tree dynamically at runtime will not be tracked.</summary>
    public class UIReseter : UIElement {

        public int searchDepth { get; set; } = int.MaxValue;

        protected override void OnVisualParentChanged(DO oldParent){
            if (VisualParent is FE p) p.Loaded += (s, e)  =>  bind(p);
        }

        private void bind(FE parent, int dl = 0) {
            if (parent == null || dl > searchDepth) return;
            var chs = H.GetChildren(parent);
            foreach (object ch in chs) {
                if (ch is UIReseter r && r != this) throw new Exception($@"There's overlapping ""{nameof(UIReseter)}"" instance in the tree. Use single global instance of check ""{nameof(UIReseter.searchDepth)}"" levels.");
                if (ch is IChangeNotifer sc) trackObject(sc, parent);
                else bind(ch as FE, ++dl);
            }
        }

        private Dictionary<IChangeNotifer, Reseter> tracked = new Dictionary<IChangeNotifer, Reseter>();
        private void trackObject(IChangeNotifer sc, FE parent) {
            var cp = getContentProperty(parent);
            if (cp == null) return;
            var r = tracked.nev(sc, () => new Reseter {
                child = sc,
                parent = parent,
                content = cp,
            });
            r.track();
        }

        private PropertyInfo getContentProperty(FE parent) {
            var pt = parent.GetType();
            var cp = parent.GetType().GetProperties(
                BindingFlags.Public |
                BindingFlags.Instance
            ).FirstOrDefault(i => Attribute.IsDefined(i,
                typeof(ContentPropertyAttribute)));
            return cp ?? pt.GetProperty("Content");
        }

        private class Reseter {
            public DO parent;
            public IChangeNotifer child;
            public PropertyInfo content;
            private bool isTracking = false;

            /// <summary>Function called by <see cref="IChangeNotifer"/> on <see cref="IChangeNotifer.MODIFIED"/> event.</summary>
            /// <param name="ch"></param>
            public void reset(object ch) {
                if(! isChildOf(child, parent)) return;
                //TODO: Handle multi-child parents
                content.SetValue(parent, null);
                content.SetValue(parent, child);
            }

            public void track() {
                if (isTracking) return;
                child.MODIFIED += reset;
            }

            private bool isChildOf(IChangeNotifer ch, DO p) {
                if(ch is DO dch) {
                    if (H.GetParent(dch) == p) return true;
                    child.MODIFIED -= reset; isTracking = false;
                    return false;
                }
                var chs = H.GetChildren(p);
                foreach (var c in chs) if (c == ch) return true;
                child.MODIFIED -= reset; isTracking = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class DictionaryExtension {
        public static V nev<K,V>(this Dictionary<K,V> d, K k, Func<V> c) {
            if (d.ContainsKey(k)) return d[k];
            var v = c(); d.Add(k, v); return v;
        }
    }
    
}
```

It could be improved and it not fully tested but it works for current purposes.
Additional problem is that some elements like `TextBox` cry about not suppopring `SomeContent`, like it is so hard to use `ToString()`... but that is another story, and is not related to my question.

Answer (score -1):

Updated answer:

I'd throw away implementing SomeContent as a Dependency property and use a UserControl instead:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.SomeContent"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding some, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SomeContent}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then in code behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for SomeContent.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class SomeContent : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty someProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(some), typeof(string),
            typeof(SomeContent),
            new PropertyMetadata("")
        );

    public string some
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(someProperty);
        set => SetValue(someProperty, value);
    }

    public SomeContent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Next, implement a view model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _somePropertyOnMyViewModel;
    public string SomePropertyOnMyViewModel
    {
        get => _somePropertyOnMyViewModel;
        set { _somePropertyOnMyViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of MyViewModel in your view and assign it to your view's DataContext:

```
public class MyView : Window
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

Then, finally, in MyView use the markup I provided in my original answer:

```
<Label>
    <local:SomeContent x:Name="SomeContent" some="{Binding 
SomePropertyOnMyViewModel" />
</Label>
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all, and should be deleted. Binding the property to a view model property won't solve the problem. It is absolutely not "*hard to imagine why simply setting a binding on the label won't work*". The reason is obviously that `ToString()` is not supposed to be called when the property changes.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it I didn't actually checked the code I posted and It turns out it is actually working. It was not the fault of the label not but was a internal bug in original code.  Some basically I set `<local:SomeContent x:Name="SomeContent" some="abc">` and that's it. It updates automatically and I don't need any binning here :)

Comment: @Clemens I didn't see your comment but this is actually working - the `ToString()` is called when `some` property is changed.

Comment: @Pawcio Didn't you say that `SomeContent.some = "xyz";` *will not cause the label to update it's view*?

Comment: Yes I said that, but that was not true - the code posted here is actually a "lite" version of original one, and I didn't checked the `lite` version properly before posting the question, sorry... :|

Comment: @Clemens Nope, It's not working :( I thought it was working because I've set `SomeContent.some = "xyz";` in `MainWindow()` constructor and I believe this is just updated after constructing the window but it doesn't work on events callbacks...

Comment: My original answer was an imcomplete edit, my apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I agree that as it stood, my original answer should have been deleted. Further, the updated answer doesn't support setting a value in xaml. One could argue that doing so violates the separation of concerns that views and models are designed to enforce. That said, one could define the view model collection in XAML. Finally, your sample doesn't work because without binding "some" to a visual element, there isn't anyone listening to the invocation of the PropertyChanged event. With binding there isn't a way to set an original value in XAML, only in code when you define the dependency property.

Comment: Sorry, but this is more complicated that all other methods that I already have and more importantly `some` value is displayed in `TextBox` and not actual label. Did you test this? I'm not sure if this will even work.

Comment: It's a very useful (and frequently used) pattern for creating highly reusable, arbitrarily complex visuals that play well with MVVM applications. You'll find this pattern in a number of Microsoft control authoring documents online such as the previously mentioned Control Authoring guide. And yes, it works. Load it up and give it a try before you dismiss it.